# How to execute content script in view-scource scheme?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, view-source

I want to excecute content script in view-scource scheme.
As in the content script match patter they didn't specified it.
Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Thats it there is no way to do so?

Comment: ok i found another way of getting the source code is using document.documentElement.innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

We can't do that.

Further details. Rendering and script execution is not allowed to happen when  opening a webpage in view-source mode.

By design, Google Chrome will initiate a new GET request to the server and provide the client browser with the unrendered version of the webpage when in view-source mode.

Check this out a related issue is discussed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84818/does-browser-view-source-mode-avoid-scripting-attacks).